# Building a list from two observable sources in RxKotlin/RxJava using collectInto

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room, collect, rx-kotlin

I have a `Category` data class and a `Plan` data class.
Each `Category` has a list of plan ids. There are Categories and Plans stored via Room.  I am trying to construct a local `List<Any>` where I add each category to a list, and then add each of it's plans.

So for each category, add the category to the list, then add each plan that belongs to that category.

The final result would look something like this...

```
0 -> a Category
1 -> a Plan
2 -> a Plan
3 -> a Plan
4 -> a Category
5 -> a Plan
```

etc.

The following calls sucessfully return an `Observable<List<Category>>` and an `Observable<Plan>`

```
AppDatabase
   .getDatabase(context)
   .categoryDao()
   .getAll()

AppDatabase.getDatabase(context).planDao().getPlan(planId)
```

Here I am trying to build my list, but it actually never emits when I subscribe to it. No completion, or error. Everything else in the stream get's hit. Why can't I get my final result?

```
    fun fetchCategoriesAndPlans() {
    val items = mutableListOf<Any>()
    AppDatabase
        .getDatabase(context)
        .categoryDao()
        .getAll()
        .concatMap { listOfCategories ->
            listOfCategories.toObservable()
        }
        .doOnNext { category ->
            items.add(category)
        }
        .concatMap { category ->
            category.getPlanIds()!!.toObservable()
        }
        .flatMap { planId ->
            AppDatabase.getDatabase(context).planDao().getPlan(planId)
        }.collectInto(items, BiConsumer{ list, i ->
            Log.d(TAG, "Collect into")
            list.add(i)
        })
        .subscribeBy(
            onSuccess = {
                Log.d(TAG, "Got the list")
            },
            onError = {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't build list ${it.message}", it)
            })
}
```

Comment: The reason the code wouldn't work is the `collectInto()`. `collectInto()` does not emit anything until the source stream completes. `.categoryDao().getAll()` on Room returns an infinite stream which never completes. The given answer would work because the answer uses `Single`, instead of `Observable`.

Comment: `val items = mutableListOf<Any>(); doOnNext { items.add(it) }` wouldn't have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make a demo base on your case which help emit both `Category` and `Plan`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...

    getCategories()
        .flattenAsObservable { it }
        .flatMap { getPlanWithCategory(it) }
        .toList()
        .subscribe({
            for (item in it) {
                Log.i("TAG", " " + item.javaClass.canonicalName)
            }
        }, {

        })
}

fun getPlanWithCategory(category: Category): Observable<Any> {
    val getPlansObservable = Observable.fromArray(category.planIds).flatMapIterable {
        it
    }.flatMap {
        getPlan(it).toObservable()
    }
    return Observable.concat(Observable.just(category), getPlansObservable)
}


fun getPlan(planId: String): Single<Plan> {
    return Single.just(Plan())
}

fun getCategories(): Single<List<Category>> {
    val categories = arrayListOf<Category>()
    categories.add(Category(arrayListOf("1", "2", "3")))
    categories.add(Category(arrayListOf("1", "2")))
    return Single.just(categories)
}

class Category(val planIds: List<String>)

class Plan
```

Out put

```
 I/TAG:  Category
 I/TAG:  Plan
 I/TAG:  Plan
 I/TAG:  Category
 I/TAG:  Plan
 I/TAG:  Plan
```

Hope it help

Comment: That worked great, any idea why mine wasn't working?

Comment: Sorry. I don't know, I try to take your code and testing to find the problem but it always have combine error (and I can not fix it), then I make a new way base on my knowledge.